# Jquery script issue

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty new with jQuery.
Trying to write a simple script to slide up and slide down.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('header').is(':visible')) {
        $('header').hide(function () {
            $(".masterhead").mouseover(function () {
                $("header").slideDown('slow');
            });
        });
    } else {
        $('.masterhead').mouseout(function () {
            $('header').slideUp('slow');
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

The problem is when I'm trying to see it in the browser, it keeps sliding up and down not the correct beahvior i was hoping, I tried with SlideToggle but the same thing happens. I tried a lot of solutions from this site but the same thing.
I will appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I think you should use mouseenter and mouseleave instead, sometimes mouseover and mouseout is executed when you moving a mouse over the item.

Comment: what is header? is header a tag? are you sure you don't want use #header or .header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this but make sure you dont want use `$('#header')` or `$('.header')` instead of `$('header')`:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('header').hide();
        $(".masterhead").hover(
        function() {
            $("header").slideDown('slow');
        },
        function() {
            $("header").slideUp('slow');
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks a lot , it works better , but sometimes it keeps doing the same thing up and down , but the correct one i want is , slide down if header is not visible  and stop and slideup when mouse is out the div

Comment: i think its ok can you provide a JSFIDDLE

Comment: i can do better , you can check it out there [demo](http://spotlight.comuv.com) it's demo

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#header').hide();
            $(".masterhead").mouseover(function () {
                $("#header").slideDown('slow');
            });

        $('.masterhead').mouseout(function () {
            $('#header').slideUp('slow');
        });


});
```

and here is the sample html

```
<div class="masterhead">hello </div>
<div id="header">hi</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle****[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gTsHf/6/)****

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Update

I fix it , i found a solution here . i don't know if best practice but seems work the way i was hoping .
 i add .stop(true, true) before calling the slideDown or slideup function.

Solution

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('header').hide();
                $(".masterhead").hover(
                function() {
                    $("header").stop(true,true).slideDown('slow');
                },
                function() {
                    $("header").stop(true,true).slideUp('slow');
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

more easilly using slideToggle:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $('header').hide();
                $('.masterhead').hover(function(){
                      $('header').slideToggle('slow');
                });

});
```